# parse_dates doesn't work with default datetime format

Tags: date, csv, pandas

I am exporting data in datetime format to csv.  When I import it back, I need to be able to read the data in as dates without any column name or column number references.

It looks like Pandas read_csv has options to automatically parse dates into datetime format but it doesn't seem to be working here.

```
# Create date data
df_list = [['2014-01-01','2014-02-01'],['2015-01-01','2015-02-01']]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list,columns=['date1','date2'])

# Convert to datetime format
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1']) 

# Export to csv
df.to_csv('_csv_file.csv',index=False)

# Read in the data and parse dates
in_df = pd.read_csv('_csv_file.csv',parse_dates=True,infer_datetime_format=True)

# Dates are not of correct type
print df.dtypes
print 
print in_df.dtypes

Out [1]:

date1    datetime64[ns]
date2            object
dtype: object

date1    object
date2    object
dtype: object
```

Is there any way to automatically parse the date columns on import without identifying the column names or locations explicitly?

Comment: You have to explicitly tell pandas which columns to treat as datetime, this is because it's possible to parse numeric values as epoch times or values like 20150110 as strings as well as 2015-01-10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can change `True` to `['date1']` in parameter `parse_dates` of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), because `True` means parsing `index` and `['date1']` parsing column `date1`:

```
# Read in the data and parse dates
in_df = pd.read_csv('_csv_file.csv', parse_dates=['date1'], infer_datetime_format=True )

#second solution
#instead column name - number of column
#in_df = pd.read_csv('_csv_file.csv',parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True )

# Dates are not of correct type
print df.dtypes
print 
print in_df.dtypes

date1    datetime64[ns]
date2            object
dtype: object

date1    datetime64[ns]
date2            object
dtype: object
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **parse_dates** : boolean, list of ints or names, list of lists, or dict, default False
>
> If True -> try parsing the index. If [1, 2, 3] -> try parsing columns 1, 2, 3 each as a separate date column. If [[1, 3]] -> combine columns 1 and 3 and parse as a single date column. {‘foo’ : [1, 3]} -> parse columns 1, 3 as date and call result ‘foo’ A fast-path exists for iso8601-formatted dates.
>
> **infer_datetime_format** : boolean, default False
>
> If True and parse_dates is enabled for a column, attempt to infer the datetime format to speed up the processing

It works, if you set column `date1` as index:

```
# Read in the data and parse dates
in_df = pd.read_csv('_csv_file.csv', parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True, 
                    index_col='date1' )

# Dates are not of correct type

print 
print in_df.dtypes
print in_df.index

date2    object
dtype: object
DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-01', '2015-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'date1', freq=None)
```

EDIT:

If you want parse all columns to `datetime`, you can specify all columns by numbers of columns to parameter `parse_dates`:

```
in_df = pd.read_csv('_csv_file.csv', parse_dates=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

But there can be errors - some `integers` can be parsed as `datetimes` e.g.:

```
print df
print df.dtypes

       date1       date2  int1      int2
0 2014-01-01  2014-02-01  2000  20111230
1 2015-01-01  2015-02-01  2014  20151230
date1    datetime64[ns]
date2            object
int1              int64
int2              int64
dtype: object

print 
print in_df
print in_df.dtypes

       date1      date2       int1       int2
0 2014-01-01 2014-02-01 2000-01-01 2011-12-30
1 2015-01-01 2015-02-01 2014-01-01 2015-12-30
date1    datetime64[ns]
date2    datetime64[ns]
int1     datetime64[ns]
int2     datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is a good explanation so I am going to accept it if nothing else comes up but one of the problems is that I am not going to know ahead of time which columns will be dates so I am hoping to find something to automatically detect and parse date columns.

Comment: Hmmm, are some columns `numeric` and some `datetime` type? Or all columns are `string` and `datetime` type?

Comment: "the problems is that I am not going to know ahead of time which columns will be dates so I am hoping to find something to automatically detect and parse date colum" - did you find a solution?